# How to use Python subprocess.run when the command contains a hyphen?

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to run the following command using `subprocess.run`, but I think the hyphen in the command `ir-keytable`, is confusing the parser. What's the best way to solve this?

```
ir-keytable -t -s rc0
```

The error:

```
stdout: 
stderr: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ir' is not defined
```

My code:

```
import subprocess
import sys

result = subprocess.run(
    [sys.executable, "-c", "ir-keytable('-t -s rc0')"], capture_output=True, text=True
)
print("stdout:", result.stdout)
print("stderr:", result.stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Syntax is giving error for any command, you should just try this :

```
import subprocess

# If you just want to run command then this :
result=subprocess.run("<>")

# But if you want to get result of your command the this:
result=subprocess.check_output("<>")
print(result.decode("utf-8")) # It returns byte type data, so we are converting that into utf-8
```

Comment: subprocess.check_output("<>") throws an error when I add command line parameters eg. "ir-keytable -t -s rc0"

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/ir-keytable -t -s rc0': '/usr/bin/ir-keytable -t -s rc0'

Comment: I don't really know about that command, I have answered you from python side, how to implement that. But that error basically mean that there is no such file as `ir-keytable`! Is that really a file name? I don't think so.

Comment: @ZXSpectrum48K are you sure about you have installed `ir-keytable`??

Comment: I think subprocess likes command parameters like this: subprocess.run(['ir-keytable', '-t', '-s', 'rc0'], capture_output=True)

Comment: yes and no. Firstly your answer gave me the information I needed to overcome the hyphen problem I originally mentioned. A complication arose from the process I chose to run, ir-keytable. This program loops continuously and outputs which key has been pressed on an IR remote control. Subsequently, subprocess.check_output should instead be replaced by subprocess.Popen with Poll

Comment: Yes, my question was answered, thank you. No, my code not working as I expected since switching to Popen and Poll. Instead of capturing live output from my proces, ir-keytable, its only outputting in bursts. But that's for another topic (!) It appears to be down to an unusual way ir-keytable outputs its data. I tried it with other programs and they output live data fine. So I'm just researching the issue instead of posting on here.

Comment: Does `shell=True` solves your issue? If you had done enought research and still not found the answer then you may post new question, with all data from research. But note all data don't mean make a question long.

Comment: No, shell=True doesn't solve the issue. Thank you, I'll continue research and post a new question if required. Thank you for you help and patience.

Comment: What should I post the answer here? After doing what your partial issue is solved? I think I will edit my answer to that. :)